# Facebook Graph API: read posts by other apps on users wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

this is my first question on stackoverflow. Tried searching for this but none of the answers helped.

The problem is that im trying to use Graph API's read_stream permission to read the users stream. That works (mostly) but what i'm really instrested is posts from other apps like Endomondo and Runtastic (sports tracking stuff) -- but they dont show up at the graph explorer, only posts by the user himself.

What can i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need the proper OG action permission. For example, assuming Runtastic is a fitness action application, you will use `user_actions.fitness` permission and then call `/me/fitness.runs`

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "10101174611725617", 
      "from": {
        "name": "☃", 
        "id": "4"
      }, 
      "start_time": "2013-05-24T20:22:26+0000", 
      "end_time": "2013-05-24T20:22:26+0000", 
      "publish_time": "2013-05-24T20:22:26+0000", 
      "application": {
        "name": "runtastic.com", 
        "namespace": "runtastic", 
        "id": "162918433202"
      }, 
      "data": {
        "course": {
          "id": "375109895929036", 
          "url": "http://www.runtastic.com/en/users/☃/sport-sessions/75329736", 
          "type": "fitness.course", 
          "title": "a 0h 0m 20s run"
        }
      }, 
      "type": "fitness.runs", 
      "no_feed_story": false, 
      "likes": {
        "count": 0, 
        "can_like": true, 
        "user_likes": false
      }, 
      "comments": {
        "count": 0, 
        "can_comment": true, 
        "comment_order": "chronological"
      }
    },
```

Comment: Does not seem to work. It says on my timeline, that i've ran 4.2 miles with runtastic.com, shows me the length, timespan, calories etc -- the full story. But i dont see it when calling `/me/fitness.runs` (or walks/bikes) :( 
By the way, there is no permission `user_actions.fitness` (when selecting permissions for a token in the Graph API Explorer).

Comment: The permission exists, just because it doesn't appear in the API explorer doesn't mean it doesn't exist.